# Search and replace CSS values in PHP

Tags: php, css, replace

My site load a css file from other site with lot of:

```
../../1/images/pager1.png
../../2/images/pager2.png
...
../../n/images/pagern.png
```

I want replace

```
../../random/images/
```

by:

```
/images/
```

How to do in PHP

Thanks

Comment: Are you generating a CSS with PHP? Way you're explaining it, you're copying the style of other sites.

Comment: Yes Ariaan, I leech content from other site, all background images are lost. I view their css file and copy all images in .css file and stored in my_site/images. I know I can download that css file and edit but thousand of "random".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php
$filename = "filename.css";
$file  = file_get_contents($filename);
$file  = preg_replace("#\.\./.*/images/#", "/images/", $file);
file_put_contents($filename, $file);
```

Comment: Thank RezaSh. It work. That is my needed. Many thanks